# Decompiling .NET assemblies to Project structure

Tags: .net

I have an existing .NET dll. I want to decompile the source code and generate a project sturcture. Through .NET reflector, I could able to generate the source code, but noway I can save the source code to a Project structure.
Is there any other tool which can generate source code along with the Project structure for a .NET dll?

Comment: I always struggle to find sane examples of where this is required, legal, and yet the user doesn't have access to the original code.

Comment: @MarcGravell - An easy example is where you had a hard disk crash and lost all the source, or were stupid and didn't check it into source control and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

The [File Generator](http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/) is a Reflector add-in which is capable of generating source code files and project files, ready to open in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This has become available recently. However, I have not used it.

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Answer (score 0):

A decompiler is not a perfect solution.  There are many things that cannot be properly reverse engineered, but will instead be reversed into a compatible (but not exactly the same) method.

This is because optimizations alter the code, and some kinds of language constructs are just syntactic sugar and it's hard for the decompiler to know if you used the sugar or did it manually.

I don't believe that when a project is compiled, that the project structure is saved in an easy to access way.  It may be possible if you have a pdb file... but without one, probably not.